# How to add numeric value to each new product's title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and what I need to achieve is to add a unique number to each new product's title. So let's say product has a title "T-shirt" - I would love to add a number automatically like this: "105: T-shirt" after each creation of the new product.
This number can be also a product's ID. It's just needs to be unique for each new product.
I tried looking for this everywhere but I couldn't find any solution.

Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: try save_post hook and wp_update_post for it

Comment: check this.https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/ there is evaluation option on import

Answer (score 0):

Here are the working code for you. I have added random code prefix with products.

```
 add_filter('the_title', 'number_adding', 10, 2);

    function number_adding($title, $id) {
        // your custom post type name
        if('product' == get_post_type($id))
        $result = random_string(5) . '_' . $title;
        return $result;
    }

    function random_string($length) {
        $chars = "0123456789";
        $str = '';
        $size = strlen($chars);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            $str .= $chars[rand(0, $size - 1)];
        }
        return $str;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This basically adds a number, but it's weird because that number is visible only product page. Not across the site when viewing product thumbnails or cards. It also breaks up the main menu when I add this code. Not sure why.

Comment: do you mean it's not add the number in product listing page?